How can I obtain log probabilities from multiple open-source LLMs via serverless inference?
I am looking for a solution to obtain log probabilities from several open-source LLMs without deploying them myself. Specifically, I need a service offering serverless inference and logprobs for open-source models. Here's what I've explored so far, but none seem to meet my requirements:
What I Need:

Access to multiple open-source base models (not only instruction-tuned or RLHFed).
Ability to get log probabilities and the token-wise breakdown of inputs.
Serverless inference (I don't have the resources for a dedicated instance).
A platform that supports frequent switching between models.

Solutions I’ve Tried:
Together
Together seems perfect for what I need since it offers log probabilities and token echoing:
client = Together(api_key=os.environ.get("TOGETHER_API_KEY"))
kwargs = {
    "engine": "mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1",
    "echo": True,  # <---- this is important
    "logprobs": 1  # <---- and this
}
response = client.chat.completions.create(prompt="I love apples and oranges", **kwargs)

However, they only support a few non-instruction-tuned models, and I'd like access to more base models like Llama 2, Qwen, or Mistral.
Fireworks
Fireworks could be another good option, but most of the the models available are instruction-tuned.
url = "https://api.fireworks.ai/inference/v1/completions"
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}"}
payload = {
    "model": "accounts/fireworks/models/mixtral-8x22b-instruct",
    "prompt": "I love apples and oranges",
    "logprobs": 2,  # <---- this is important
    "echo": True    # <---- and this
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers)

Replicate
Replicate offers a good selection of open-source models, but log probabilities are not supported and they do not plan to support them (issue).
Anyscale
I also considered Anyscale, but they are sunsetting llm-engine (source). Their upcoming replacement, scale-gp, isn't accessible to me as I cannot reach the dashboard (link).
Banana
Banana could have been a good solution, but they're sunsetting their serverless inference (details here).
HuggingFace serverless inference
This would be ideal, but most of the "warm" models (ready to be used) are small/medium-sized, and often instruction-tuned. Loading cold models with relatively large sizes (over 10GB) isn't feasible as they often don't spin up.
Other Providers:
Platforms like OpenAI and Anthropic don't support open-source models at all, which rules them out for my needs.
What I’m Looking For:
Is there a platform that allows serverless inference with logprobs on open-source LLMs (like Qwen, Mistral, Mixtral, LLaMA 2/3/3.1, Mixtral)—ideally offering both base and instruction-tuned models? I need the flexibility to frequently switch between models without managing a dedicated instance.
Thanks for any recommendations!
